# Add search filter to observable when making http call

Tags: angular

My json is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "name": "one",
    "address": "1 Street"
  },
  {
    "name": "two",
    "address": "2 Street"
  },
  {
    "name": "three",
    "address": "3 Street"
  },
  {
    "name": "four",
    "address": "4 Street"
  },
  {
    "name": "five",
    "address": "5 Street"
  }

 ]
```

How do I filter by the `name` variable that gets passed into getCompanies against `name` above?

```
  public getCompanies(name): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer) => {
      this.http.get(this.companyApiUrl)
        .subscribe(data => {
            observer.next(data)
            observer.complete()
        }, err => observer.error(err))
    })
  }
```

Comment: Which version of rxjs are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to wrap the `http.get` in an `Observable`, as it already returns an `Observable`. Instead, you can use the `map` operator to transform the response, and the array `filter` function to look for items where the `name` property matches the one passed in.

*Please note the code below is using rxjs 6*

```
 import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

 public getCompanies(searchTerm): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get(this.companyApiUrl).pipe(
         map((arr) => arr.filter(item => !searchTerm || item.name && item.name.indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1))
     )      
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've noticed that when name is "", then there are no matches. How can I filter by something like `map((arr) => arr.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1))` instead?

Comment: @methuselah I've updated the answer for you. I've added `item.name && item.name.indexOf...` to ensure there aren't any errors if `name` is null / undefined

Comment: This change returns null if name=null or ''

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want the behaviour to be if `name` is null, and also what if `item.name` is null. Thanks

Comment: updated your answer, `searchTerm` being the variable that is passed in. if thats empty then it should display all results, right now it returns nothing

Comment: Try that. If searchTerm is empty or null, it will return all items